# Setting a path in OSX for Matlab

Tags: macos, matlab

I just shifted from a windows machine to a apple machine at work. I have no experience with apple and this is the first time I am using OSX.

I have a matlab script that I have to run on this machine but I cannot seem to get the path to my files.

My files are on a network drive. In windows its as simple as `U:\Matlab` Now I can access my files in the explorer but cannot seem to set them in Matlab using `cd`

To get the path of my files I right clicked on the folder and copied the `where` It provided me with this:

`Volumes/home9/MATLAB/`

Now to set these paths in Matlab I did this:

`cd('Volumes/home9/MATLAB/')`

But am provided with the error:

`Cannot CD to Volumes/home9/MATLAB/ (Name is nonexistent or not a directory).`

As you can tell I have no idea what I am doing. Some guidance would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: I think you meant `which`, not `where`.  Also, do you prepend your path with `/`... so `/Volumes/home9/MATLAB/`?

Comment: add the ``/`` solved the problem. Thank you. If you could add this as an answer I would be able to accept it.

Comment: You got it!  I will now.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you meant to use [`which`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/which.html), not `where`.  `where` doesn't exist in MATLAB!  Now, your problem is probably due to the fact that you need to prepend your path with `/`.  Therefore, your path should be: `/Volumes/home9/MATLAB/`.  If you don't include the `/`, it assumes that the directory is local or where MATLAB has currently defined the working directory to be.  Judging from the context, you want the absolute path of the directory, and that's why you need the `/` character as there is a `Volumes` directory in your root directory.

Try that and see if that works!

Comment: Sorry this was a mistake on my part, I had edited my username out of the path. I have fixed the above question now